# simple rmongodb query not working

Tags: r, rmongodb

I'm having trouble getting a simple rmongodb query to work.
Here is a reproducible example.

This part Doesn't work.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(rmongodb)
mongo <- mongo.create(host="localhost")
mongo.is.connected(mongo)
ns <- "mydb.test"

x <- data.frame(thread.ids=c(276097L,26509L),num.replies=c(0L,23L),stringsAsFactors = F)
x
b <- mongo.bson.from.df(x)
b
mongo.drop(mongo,ns)
mongo.insert.batch(mongo,ns,b)
a <- mongo.find.all(mongo,ns)
a
query1 <- mongo.bson.from.list(list("thread.ids"=276097L))
query1

l <- mongo.find.all(mongo,ns,query1)
l
l <- mongo.find.one(mongo,ns,query1)
l
l <- mongo.find.one(mongo,ns,'{"thread.ids" : "276097" }')
l
l <- mongo.find.one(mongo,ns,'{"thread.ids" : 276097 }')
l
```

And for some reason, this part works:

```
x <- data.frame(name=c("Dave","Fred"),age=c(27L,31L),stringsAsFactors = F)
x1 <- mongo.bson.from.df(x)
x1
mongo.insert.batch(mongo, ns, x1)
query3 <- mongo.bson.from.list(list("name"="Dave"))
query3
l <- mongo.find.one(mongo,ns,'{"name" : "Dave" }')
l
l <- mongo.find.all(mongo,ns,query3)
l
l <- mongo.find.one(mongo,ns,query3)
l
```

Thanks for any help. Even when I make the thread.ids as character, it still does not find those records.

### **UPDATE:**

Further work exposes a problem. This workflow does not accept parameter names with periods in them. For example when I rename **'thread.ids'** to **'threadids'** everything starts to work.

I've opened this issue on the github mentioned in the cran documentation:
https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb/issues/75

Comment: Can you run the query in the mongodb shell, and is it correct? Do you need to use `mongo.insert.batch` for more than one document?

Comment: Thanks tospig, you were correct that I should use insert.batch, however I uncovered another problem. Please check the update at the end of the comment.

Comment: Have a look at the new [mongolite](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mongolite/vignettes/intro.html) package.

Answer (score 1):

Try to fill your `integer` ids (if they are actually integer) in query explicitly:

```
class(26509)
class(26509L)
query1 <- mongo.bson.from.list(list('thread.ids' = 26509L))
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
After rewiewing reproducible example:
1. `b <- mongo.bson.from.df(x)` produce list of bsons
2.  `mongo.insert` see, that argument has type `list` and try to convert list to bson using `mongo.bson.from.list()`
So you end with following record in database:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5502e4cc84a98eebe8a9b5ab"),
    "1" : {
        "thread.ids" : 276097,
        "num.replies" : 0
    },
    "2" : {
        "thread.ids" : 26509,
        "num.replies" : 23
    }
}
```

if you want to insert multiple records, use `mongo.insert()` in a loop or use `mongo.insert.batch()`:

```
mongo.insert.batch(mongo,"mydb.test",b)
```

this code inserts 2 objects:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5502e65984a98eebe8a9b5ac"),
    "thread.ids" : 276097,
    "num.replies" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5502e65984a98eebe8a9b5ad"),
    "thread.ids" : 26509,
    "num.replies" : 23
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. I've made the example reproducible.

Comment: Thanks your comment helped a bit, I can sometimes get it to work and sometimes not. Please see updated reproducible examples.

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, I would suggest that mongo.insert and mongo.insert.batch could check against http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#field-names rules and error out with an informative message.  Thanks.